# Python / Selenium - can't print text contents of all paragraphs

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

Newbie here. I am trying to print all text(s) contained in each 'p' tag on a website. This is the code that does not work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com/')
elem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('p')
print(elem.text)
```

I am learning as I go, so I want to see the content that I am scraping, so I know all is good, before moving to more advanced topics. The teacher says "all web elements have the ".text" method, but does not seem to work when I try to print. Error message is:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/sk/PycharmProjects/test/temperase.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sk/PycharmProjects/test/temperase.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(elem.text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

What am I doing wrong and what's the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for generous help everyone! It's my first question ever. Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because elem is a list. So you should try the source code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com/')
elem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('p')
for el in elem:
    print(el.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the error again:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

The method find_element**s**_by_css_selector() returns a **list** of web elements. You will then have to iterate over that list, to print the .text of each one.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium webdriver "find_elements_by_css_selector" function returns objects (list of objects ) of all occurrence element on page so you need to traverse one by one and print all "p" tag content.

Same way "find_element_by_css_selector" return only first occurrence element object so you don't need to traverse, can call direct method to get content.